# How to Access URL parameter in Vue template

Tags: vue.js

Suppose a page has a URL like `http://example.com?id=5`. Is there anyway to access the parameter value directly in HTML using vue template? For example, to display the value of `id` directly in span, is there something like `<span>{{ url.id }}</span>`

Comment: are you using vue router?

Comment: nopes, new to vue, i saw a possibility of using vue router, was wondering if there is a more direct way

Comment: You could access `location`. But you shouldn't. Writing logic in templates just because you can results in awful code.

Comment: @EstusFlask is location reactive ?

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim This wasn't under discussion, but no, not at all. It needs to be integrated with history API to be reactive. And that's something that the router does.